# How to set SOAP header for webservice call

Tags: web-services, soap, vbscript

I am using the below script to get a response from a basic authenticated SOAP web service.Below code is putting credentials in HTTP header and as a result of which I am not getting the response.

How do I update credentials in SOAP header using VBScript?

My code:

```vb
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objHTTP.setOption 2, 13056

strTextContent = Trim("Content of my request xml")

strUserName = "mylogin"
strPassword = "mypassword"

strURL = "myendpoint"

objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False, strUserName, strPassword
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(strUserName & ":" & strPassword)
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "mysoapaction"

objHTTP.send strTextContent

strResponseReceived = objHTTP.responseText
MsgBox strResponseReceived
```

Comment: Are you sure that GET shouldn't be POST?

Comment: Remove **`strUserName, strPassword`** after **`objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False`** since you are using **`Basic Authorization`** using Base64Encode.

Comment: Thanks.It worked after changing to post as suggested by MrGadget.objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False, strUserName, strPassword is modified to objHTTP.Open "POST", strURL, False